# Salesforce Validation Formula

Tags: validation, salesforce

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days and can't seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to have an error fire when someone saves an opportunity:

- Multi-Select - Call Qualifying
- Checkbox - only 1 checkbox of the following can be checked

Here's the code I have so far.  There are no syntax errors

```
AND (
INCLUDES(Metric__c,"Call Qualifying"),

OR(  Call_Tagging_Client__c ,Call_Tagging_Est__c ,!Call_Tagging_Service__c  
) ,
OR(  Call_Tagging_Client__c,!Call_Tagging_Est__c ,Call_Tagging__Service__c  
) ,
OR(  !Call_Tagging_Client__c,Call_Tagging_Est__c ,Call_Tagging_Service__c  ) 
))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't already resolved this, here is a pointer: The problem in your original formula is that you are using three `OR` functions when you actually want `AND` since, for each set of three fields, you want exactly one to be checked.

Try this instead:

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Metric__c, "Call Qualifying"),
    OR(
        /* Any of the next three conditions, each for exactly one checkbox checked */
        AND(Call_Tagging_Client__c, !Call_Tagging_Est__c, !Call_Tagging_Service__c),
        AND(!Call_Tagging_Client__c, Call_Tagging_Est__c, !Call_Tagging__Service__c),
        AND(!Call_Tagging_Client__c, !Call_Tagging_Est__c, Call_Tagging_Service__c)
    )
)
```